# assign variable for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript

I have a form that collects information on 15 participants, and based on a Class selected for each participant 3 drop down boxes (Events) are populated. Originally I had a drop down box to select the Class and I have changed to a textbox.   However I cannot figure out how to associate the variable with the text box (instead of dropdown) with the Class for each participant.  This is the part of function I am having trouble with: var class_id = **class_dropdown.value**;  I have read other similar posts but cannot figure out how they associated text box and name in variable.

This is the form:

```html
<form name="myform" method="post" action="insert_entries.php">

<table style="width: 139%" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 166px"><strong>FIRST NAME</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 161px"><strong>LAST NAME</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 66px"><strong>GENDER</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 224px"><strong>DOB</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 74px"><strong>CLASS</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 104px"><strong>EVENT 1</strong></td>
  <td class="style2" style="width: 104px"><strong>EVENT 2</strong></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 166px">
<input type="text" name="first1" size="35" style="width: 155px" /></td>
  <td style="width: 161px">
<input type="text" name="last1" size="35" style="width: 155px" /></td>
  <td style="width: 66px">
<select name="gender1" class="dropdownbox" id="series id15"style="height: 23px; width: 70px">
<option></option>
<option>M</option>
<option>F</option>
</select></td>
  <td style="width: 224px">
  <input type="date" name="dob1" size="35" onchange = "repeat()" style="width: 155px; height: 27px;" /></td>
  <td style="width: 74px">
<input type="text" name="class1" size="35" style="width: 155px" /></td>
  <td style="width: 104px">
<select name="events1" class="dropdownbox" id="series id"style="height: 23px; width: 104px">
<option></option>
</select> </td>
  <td style="width: 72px">
<select name="events1B" class="dropdownbox" id="series id16"style="height: 23px; width: 104px">
<option></option>
</select> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the function:

```js
<script>
// function to get event list for selected class -
function get_event(class_dropdown)
{
 // get selected class value -
 var class_id = class_dropdown.value;
 
 // get name of selected class dropdown -
 var class_dropdown_name = $(class_dropdown).attr('name');
 
 // get no. appended to class dropdown name -
 var class_no = class_dropdown_name.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ); 
 
 // prepare names of 3 event dropdowns -
 var event1 = 'events'+class_no;
 var event2 = 'events'+class_no+'B';
 var event3 = 'events'+class_no+'C';
 
 // empty 3 event dropdowns -
 $('select[name="'+event1+'"]').html('');
 $('select[name="'+event2+'"]').html('');
 $('select[name="'+event3+'"]').html('');
 
 if(class_id != '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"get_event.php",
   type:"POST",
   dataType:"json",
   data:{class_id:class_id},
   success:function(data)
   {
    var event_option = '';
   
    event_option = event_option+'<option value=""></option>'; 
    
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
     event_option = event_option+'<option value="'+ data[i].eventcode +'">'+ data[i].event +'</option>';
    }
    
    // append event list to 3 dropdowns next immediate -
    $('select[name="'+event1+'"]').html(event_option);
    $('select[name="'+event2+'"]').html(event_option);
    $('select[name="'+event3+'"]').html(event_option);
   }
  });
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, you want to run the included Javascript and have the `class_dropdown` variable populated with a reference to your `class1` input.

There are multiple ways to do that, one of possible approaches is to inline the event call in a similar way your other input, the `dob1` calls the `repeat()` function in the `onchange` inlined handler:

```
<input type="date" name="dob1" size="35" onchange = "repeat()" ...
```

The similar approach here would be to pick one the `change` event that occurs when the input value is changed or the `blur` event that occurs when the focus is taken away from the input. Then, inline the handler call passing **this** as the reference to actual input:

```
<input name='class1' onblur="get_event(this)" />
```

In the example call from above, the `get_event` is called whenever the focus is taken away from the input and the `get_event` is called passing the `class1` reference to the method.

You can verify this in the following playgound. Just type whatever you want and focus out of the textbox. The message will display the actual value of the input.

```js
function get_event(class_dropdown) {
   var text = class_dropdown.value;
   alert(text);
}
```

```html
<input name='class1' onblur="get_event(this)" />
```

Comment: I tried a similar onchange event with the class1 input  and it didn't work.  Then I tried the onblur and it worked but I had to click in the class1 input and click several times on the events dropdown to see the items in the events dropdown.  Is there a way to fix it so that the user does not have to click in the class1 input?

Comment: @CathyAnn: impossible to answer that question without a specific example. My guess is that the AJAX call you make in the event handler just **takes some time**, it's not that you have to click anywhere but you'd just have to wait a little bit longer. To avoid that, create a visual indicator that a server call occurs in the background (and delete the indicator in the `success` handler of the AJAX call). This way your users will understand what happens in the background and they have to wait a while.